# What impacts performance on odbc_fetch_array()

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a php page that runs a query and displays about 100-200 results.

```
$sql = odbc_prepare($connection,$stmt);
odbc_execute($sql);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($sql) {
    echo $row['col1'].$row['col2'].$row['col3']."<br>";
}
```

It takes about 15 seconds to run, and most of that time seems to be inside the loop. The query itself has multiple joins, which I had thought would slow down the odbc_execute() function, not the odbc_fetch_array().

What exactly is happening when I call odbc_fetch_array()? What impacts the performance? Complexity of the query? Amount of data returned? Memory/CPU of the SQL server? Memory/CPU of the PHP server?

Comment: the exec() call is where the multiple joins would have an effect. once the exec call returns, the db's already finished the query and is ready to return rows of results.  unless you've got some massive blobs in the results, a fetch call should be fairly lightweight and NOT bog things down.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some performance increase by specifying the `cursor_type` in `odbc_connect` which will make odbc fetching much quicker.

$conn = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC)

As I can see, you are going through a loop, 100-200 results means - odbc query `odbc_fetch_array()` is running 100-200 times. Optionally you can use http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:userguide:learn_abstraction:basic_query which has a `getAll()` method to return all the data at once with out looping.

Comment: It looks like the main problem that I have is that my SQL server and PHP server are in different buildings connected over a VPN, meaning each odbc_fetch_array() call was going through the internet to get to the server.  I ended up going with PDO, which seems very similar to your ADO suggestion and the fetchAll() function works much faster than grabbing individual rows.

Answer (score 1):

Contacting the server for every row is what was causing the delay, not the complexity of the query itself. If the PHP server and SQL server were on the same network it wouldn't be as bad, but if they're on different machines connected over the internet or a VPN, it becomes noticeable.

The odbc_* functions have no option for fetching all rows at once. The option I went with was to re-write my code to use PDO and PDO->fetchall() to get all rows at once.